# Plot custom data with Tensorboard

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-visualization, tensorboard

I have a personal implementation of a RL algorithm that generates performance metrics every x time steps.

That metric is simply a scalar, so **I have an array of scalars that I want to display as a simple graph** such as:

[image]

I want to display it in real time in tensorboard like my above example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to use tensorboard you can start looking at [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started) and this [datacamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorboard-tutorial) on tensorboard.

With tensorflow you can use `summary.scalar` to plot your custom data (as the example), no need for particular format, as the summary is taking care of that, the only condition is that `data` has to be `a real numeric scalar value, convertible to a float32 Tensor.`

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

import os
import time

now = time.localtime()
subdir = time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y_%H.%M.%S", now)

summary_dir1 = os.path.join("stackoverflow", subdir, "t1")
summary_writer1 = tf.summary.create_file_writer(summary_dir1)

for cont in range(200):
    with summary_writer1.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar(name="unify/sin_x", data=np.math.sin(cont) ,step=cont)
        tf.summary.scalar(name="unify/sin_x_2", data=np.math.sin(cont/2), step=cont)
    summary_writer1.flush()
```

[image: tensorboard array of scalars]

That said, if you are not planning on using tensorflow with your implementation, I would suggest you just use matplotlib as this library also enables you to plot data in real time https://youtu.be/Ercd-Ip5PfQ?t=444.

Comment: Your answer is great, I don't know why my question got downvoted since I did not find any simple resource on that subject. Your code works perfectly, thanks.