# Is there easy way to log numpy data to tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to log some numpy (array) data to tensorboard. But I can't find any simple method. I found a bit complicated way to do this by using summary histogram, but I want some simple ways.

Comment: Please provide some code samples of what you already have and then describe what you would like to add/change. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly take a tour of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Maybe this can fit your requisites https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377596/13144143