# Tensorboard: Use custom x-values

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I have a prediction model that predicts several future states of a system. I calculate metrics per future timestep. So after the test run is finished I return a dictionary like this:

```
metrics = {'mae_0': some_scalar, 'mse_0': some_scalar, 
           'mae_1': some_scalar, 'mse_1:' some_scalar, 
           'mae_2': ...
            .
            .
            . 
            'mae_n': some_scalar, 'mse_n': some_scalar}
```

I'd like to plot these in tensorboard with [0, 1, 2, ..., n] as the x-values.
However from what I found so far I can only use step, batch or epoch as x-value, which is identical so I get a vertical line of values instead of a plot.

Is there a way to provide custom x-values to the tensorboard logger?

Comment: Have you got a chance to look at `tf.summary.scalar`?. You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377596/11530462) for reference and let us know if that is what you're looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have since moved one to a different part of the project, but will bookmark this for future reference.